# Geforce gt650m laptop driver

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu

Ubuntu was working with default mesa graphic drivers. I tried to install nvidia driver for my geforce gt650m. I installed different versions of nvidia 319, 310, etc. All of them installed but my entire UI system crashed. Now my login screen looks so small, i don't have desktop or unity.

I am running 13.04.

My story about the Nvidia drivers: At first `apt-get install nvidia-current`, removed it later.

Then i just downloaded nvidia 319 310 313 different versions with wget stopped gdm and just run `./NVIDIA`

Answer (score 0):

So you have Optimus-CUDA graphics card with Geforce GT650M ?

Here is a good (off-topic) - link - but there is anything explained:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/297030/nvidia-frickle-with-hybrid-chipset-is-now-over-finally

You need this package as driver :

CUDA SDK 1.1 Beta for Linux

You find it between center and below at "Download" - Link :

http://www.nvidia.de/object/cuda_1_1_beta.html

Comment: It said i need kernel interface,  then said It will download from ftp site, then said its not found, then asked for kernel source, i have linux-headers and linux-source for my kernel ver. Still not works, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before. Try this, if this might works with you..

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```